# PostgreSQL: Only allow users to execute procedures, but avoid access to any other resources such as tables?

Tags: postgresql

I want to limit the type and scope of all operations that a user can make in order to protect the database.

How can I tell PostgreSQL that a given user is only allowed the execution of stored procedures, and not to read or write tables directly?

If there are better ways to do this I am also opened to suggestions :)

Thanks!

Comment: Don't grant privileges on the tables and only grant `execute` on the functions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just tried that and it seems the privileges don't cascade during the function call. At least not in version 9.5. My test user can call the function, but it fails because he doesn't have the table permissions.

Comment: You need to create the function with `security definer`